# How to combine multiple languages in a single project?

Tags: localization

Is it possible, for instance, to use functions of a C++ library in another language like Java or Ruby? Can a single application be programmed using separated languages? How?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is quite possible to create a program that uses multiple languages. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542520/how-can-i-call-c-functions-from-within-ruby) is a post for using C++ from Ruby. As for Java, you'll want to look at the [Java Native Interface](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html).

A program can be coded using different languages either by inline code (e.g., Assembly language in a C/C++ program, or MATLAB code inside of LabVIEW blocks). Or, by calling external library code (e.g., C# interoperability with C/C++ libraries).

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to embed C/C++ code in another language. For example, take a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/):

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is used with different types of target languages including common scripting languages such as Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and Ruby.