# How to write a Rack adapter with C

Tags: ruby, rack, g-wan

I would like to see if it is possible to exchange data between g-wan server and ruby but I need to implement a Rack adapter. I could write one in Ruby, but I need to use C because g-wan API is in C (or Java). Is there any documentation to do that? Does Rack has a C API?

Comment: Note that starting with v3.10, G-WAN supports Ruby servlets, resolving your problem effortlessly  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could open OS pipe from ruby and write some data into it, then receive it from your C program.
2. It is possible to write extensions to Ruby in C.  Just search the Internet for resources on this topic.
3. Use JRuby, it runs on JVM and allows you to use arbitrary jars.  Also, it is really good Ruby VM and has strong community.

Comment: Yes but how can I write an adapter for Rack, where is a tutorial? I do not think a pipe is a good idea, G-WAN is multithreaded. Probably this thing is too big for me, but there must be a starting point somewhere.

Comment: [Read this](http://intridea.com/posts/rack-middleware-and-applications-whats-the-difference) for brief introduction on Rack applications. All you need is a class app with single `call(env)` instance method.  You can make this class entirely in C using functions like `rb_define_class`, refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542520/how-can-i-call-c-functions-from-within-ruby).  You can also write it in Ruby (what will be more elegant), but still at some point you have to prepare Ruby adapter to this API using those C functions.