# linux define global keyboard shortcuts in ruby (+Qt)

Tags: ruby, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I define+handle global keyboard in the ruby desktop application? 
I'm running Linux and using Qt. My program should be in the system tray and whenever some global keyboard shortcut is pushed, it should handle it.

Comment: I suppose you need to hook into the WM for that.

Comment: libqxt http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home has global shortcuts

Comment: @Kamil: I didn't see any ruby bindings to libqxt, is there an easy way to use the library in ruby?

Comment: Well this is topic for another question. Someone already asked it at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542520/how-can-i-call-c-functions-from-within-ruby

Comment: @KamilKlimek thanks a lot! I think I'll try the approach suggested by you and see how far I come :) if you're interested, post your comments in an answer (to get points) as I consider your answer as the correct/complete one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get global shortcuts using [libqxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home) (as you're already using Qt it shouldn't bother you). If you need to use them directly in Ruby then you should check this question: [How can I call C++ functions from within ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542520/how-can-i-call-c-functions-from-within-ruby)